# The "Builder-style usage of methods that return Unit" on Kotlin website confuse me

Tags: kotlin

The **Idioms** section of the official Kotlin docs contains [this example](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/idioms.html#builder-style-usage-of-methods-that-return-unit):

> #### Builder-style usage of methods that return Unit
>
> ```
> fun arrayOfMinusOnes(size: Int): IntArray {
>     return IntArray(size).apply { fill(-1) }
> }
> ```

As the function `apply` returns the generic type, and I thought `Unit` is as same as `void` in Java, this section is suggesting we can use a void method in builder-style? That doesn't make sense to me - what's it trying to say?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point it's trying to make is that if you just did traditional Java builder style, like this:

```
return IntArray(size)
    .fill(-1)
```

then it wouldn't compile, because it's of type `Unit`, not `IntArray`. 
 So traditionally, you'd have to do something like this:

```
val ret = IntArray(size)
ret.fill(-1)
return ret
```

`apply` enables you to avoid this, because the return type is still of type `IntArray` (or `T`, in general).

Comment: So it means use "apply" function as a wrapper of any void method, so than the builder can keep?

Comment: @ShangXubin - `apply` can be used to wrap any number of methods, but it always returns the object.

Answer (score 1):

Take this one:

```
class X {
    var a: Int? = null
    var b: Int? = null
    fun first(a: Int) = apply { this.a = a }
    fun second(b: Int) = apply { this.b = b }
}

X().first(2).second(3)
```

The `apply` functions are used to return the instance of `X` after setting the property. This enables builder-style call of both methods. If `apply` were removed, the function would return `Unit`.